# Преобразование изображения, полученного в onPictureTaken()

Tags: java, android, камера

Имеется активность с `SurfaceView` и `ImageButton`. В `SurfaceView` выводятся фреймы, полученные с камеры. При нажатии на кнопку вызывается метод `Camera.takePicture(...)`, а в методе `onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)` я создаю новую активность и передаю туда массив байтов изображения.

Код `MainActivity`:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.example.user.task8.R;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback, Camera.PictureCallback {

  private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

  private static final String PHOTO_DIR = "Task8";

  private Camera camera;
  private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
  private SurfaceView preview;
  private ImageButton shotButton;

  public void takePicture(View view) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//    Window settings
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.a_main);

    preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);

    surfaceHolder = preview.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    shotButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_shot);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    camera = Camera.open();

//    It is way to fix freezing a surface on screen locking
    preview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

//    It is way to fix freezing a surface on screen locking
    preview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (camera != null) {
      camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
      camera.stopPreview();
      camera.release();
      camera = null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
      camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
      camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }

    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    float aspect = (float) previewSize.width / previewSize.height;

    int previewSurfaceWidth = preview.getWidth();
    int previewSurfaceHeight = preview.getHeight();

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = preview.getLayoutParams();

    lp.height = previewSurfaceHeight;
    lp.width = (int) (previewSurfaceHeight / aspect);

    preview.setLayoutParams(lp);

    camera.startPreview();
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PictureActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PictureActivity.PICTURE_DATA, data);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

В новой активности декодирую массив в битмапу, её в свою очередь переворачиваю и вывожу в `ImageView`. Но качество полученного изображения, мягко говоря, ужасно.

Код `PictureActivity`:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.user.task8.R;

public class PictureActivity extends Activity {

  public static final String PICTURE_DATA = "PICTURE_DATA";

  private static final String TAG = "PictureActivity";

  private ImageView imageView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //    Window settings
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.a_picture);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture_view);

    byte[] data = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra(PICTURE_DATA);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
  }
}
```

**Вопрос**: как можно получить качество картинки такое же, как в превью? И можно ли получить такое изображение, используя существующую структуру приложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй `params.setPictureSize()`. Подробнее смотри в **Camera.Parameters**

`params.getSupportedPictureSizes()` возвращает список поддерживаемых размеров.  Надо выбрать нужный размер и указать его с помощью `setPictureSize()`

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();


Camera.Size sizePicture = (one of the sizes from supportedSizes list);

params.setPictureSize(sizePicture.width, sizePicture.height);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!